# Frame property of CABasicAnimation is not animating?

Tags: ios, calayer, cabasicanimation

In my application I try to add the following animation with keyPath `frame` as below

```
CABasicAnimation *animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
    animation.duration=0.6;
    animation.repeatCount=1;
    animation.delegate=self;
    animation.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    animation.fromValue=[NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.layer.frame];
    animation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGRect:rect];//rect is a new frame 
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"frameChange"];
    [self setFrame:rect];
```

the animation is not happening with the above method but
successfully I got the delegate method `animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:`
called back.

But the below animation to position property is working well

```
CABasicAnimation *animation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration=0.6;
animation.repeatCount=1;
animation.delegate=self;
animation.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
animation.fromValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:self.layer.position];
animation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:rect.origin];
[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"frameChange"];
```

Why the frame property is not animating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frame is not an animatable property. You have to make an animation for position and bounds. To have them both time together, place them inside of a CAAnimationGroup.